What was the post of Vyasadeva?
Was Vyasa deva a Rishi, a Maharshi a Bramharshi or a Devarshi.
Do any texts mention his designation.kindly answer.

Vyasa is equated to Vishnu himself in the Dhyanasloka of Vishnu Sahasranama.  He is given the title of mahamuni महामुनि or "great sage".
https://ramanuja.org/sri/BhaktiListArchives/Article?p=mar96%2F0037.html


vyAsam vasishta-naptAram Sakteh pautram akalmasham
parAsarAtmajam vande Suka-tAtam tapo-nidhim.



[  vyAsa is the great-grandson of vasishta and the grand-son of
Sakti. He is the son of parAsara and the father of Suka. I offer
my obeisance to that vyAsa who is free from all defects and is
a mine of austerities.  ]



vyAsAya vishNu-rUpAya vyAsa-rUpAya vishNave
namo vai Brahma-nidhaye vAsishtAya namo namaH.



[  My repeated salutations to vyAsa who is a form of vishNu and to
vishNu who is a form of vyAsa- sage vyAsa, who is a descendent
of vasishta and who is a treasure of brahman, (i.e. vedas).  ]



vishNoH nAma-sahasrasya veda-vyAso mahA-muniH
chandaH-anushtup tathA devo bhagavAn devakI-sutaH.



[   The great vedavyAsa is the Rshi of these Thousand Names of
vishNu; anushtup is its metre.  The presiding diety is Lord
Krishna,  devakI's son.  ]


Is Narada ji also a mahamuni? Narad ji is said to be a Devarshi..Is there any other description of vyasadeva citing his rishitva?
